# If a.i=4, then ,what is the value of (axj).(2j-3k) , where a is a vector

Tags: vectors, cross-product

This is a question I saw in a question paper of a competitive exam but I was unable to solve it. Can anyone please assist me with any sort of hint to solve this problem and any type of explanation if needed in the hint. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a\cdot i=4$ means that $a=4i+sj+tk$ where $s$ and $t$ are real, and so
$a\times j=4k-ti$. Now take the dot product with $2j-3k$; I think that pesky $t$
will obligingly vanish.

Answer (score 0):

$$(a\times\mathbf{j})\cdot(2\mathbf{j}-3\mathbf{k}) = a\cdot(\mathbf{j}\times (2\mathbf{j}-3\mathbf{k})
= a\cdot(-3\mathbf{i}) = (4\mathbf{i})\cdot (-3\mathbf{i}) = -12$$

Comment: How can you exchange the cross and dot product?

Comment: @Esha This is the "scalar triple product identity": $(u\times v)\cdot w=u\cdot(v\times w)$.

Comment: Ook! Got it. Thanks for the explanation